# PHPExcel error in CodeIgniter "Unable to load the requested class: iofactory"

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm trying to export an XLS file with PHPExcel 1.7.8 + CodeIgniter 2.1.3

I have followed all the instructions from [PHPExcel](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PHPExcel)

but I'm getting this error:

> > Unable to load the requested class: `iofactory`

and here's my Controller code:

```
    //expoxt to excel all admin data
function export_excel_admin()
{
    //$data['resultsadmin'] = $this->admin_model->get_all_data_admin();
    //var_dump($data['resultsadmin']);
    //$this->load->view('administrator/export_excel/export_excel_admin', $data);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_admin');

    if(!$query)
        return false;

    // Starting the PHPExcel library
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $this->load->library('PHPexcel/IOFactory');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Field names in the first row
    $fields = $query->list_fields();
    $col = 0;
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
        $col++;
    }

    // Fetching the table data
    $row = 2;
    foreach($query->result() as $data)
    {
        $col = 0;
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field);
            $col++;
        }

        $row++;
    }

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    // Sending headers to force the user to download the file
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Products_'.date('dMy').'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter->save('php://output');

}
```

Ah also I have removed the "PHPExcel_" part in IOFactory.php file
any solution for this issue?

Comment: Have you modified the PHPExcel autoloader as well? So that it knows that IOFactory is actually a part of PHPExcel? Personally I wouldn't have followed that advice to change PHPExcel class names; but set it up to use the autoloader correctly in vendor space

Comment: @MarkBaker : nope, I've just removed "PHPExcel_" part in IOFactory.php, but actually the problem still occurs even if I don't remove the "PHPExcel_" part..

Comment: I find it really difficult to help... I don't use PHPExcel in any framework, but the PHPExcel autoloader should work as a fully SPL compliant autoloader with any framework, without needing to change class names or PHPExcel code in any way. http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework might give an alternative to integrating PHPExcel into Codeigniter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used PHPExcel with CodeIgniter successfully before.

All I did was drop the phpexcel folder into application/third-party and created the following wrapper library:

```
<?php

class Excel {

    private $excel;

    public function __construct() {
        // initialise the reference to the codeigniter instance
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/phpexcel/PHPExcel.php';
        $this->excel = new PHPExcel();    
    }

    public function load($path) {
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
        $this->excel = $objReader->load($path);
    }

    public function save($path) {
        // Write out as the new file
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save($path);
    }

    public function stream($filename) {       
        header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\""); 
        header("Cache-control: private");        
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');    
    }

    public function  __call($name, $arguments) {  
        // make sure our child object has this method  
        if(method_exists($this->excel, $name)) {  
            // forward the call to our child object  
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->excel, $name), $arguments);  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  
}

?>
```

I could then do the following in my controllers:

```
$this->load->library("excel");
$this->excel->load("/path/to/input.xls");
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', "whatever");
$this->excel->save("/path/to/output.xls");
```

Hope this helps you out?

Comment: did you change anything in the PHPExcel Class?

Comment: Not a sausage.. Dropped it in straight from the zip file

Comment: My excel file is downloaded on when i test on windows machine but fails when deployed on linux machine with https enabled

Comment: hi.can u help me about export to excel

Comment: @devrooms  as Dipen says any solution. I am also facing same problem (ubuntu ec2  with https)

Comment: @Dipen have you got  solution

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this comment was too late. But maybe useful for others.

Change the part code below:

```
// Starting the PHPExcel library
$this->load->library('excel');
$this->load->library('PHPexcel/IOFactory');
```

to:

```
// Starting the PHPExcel library
$this->load->library('excel');
//$this->load->library('PHPexcel/IOFactory');
```

Then change this part code too:

```
 $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
```

to:

```
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is

```
//afrer this you can use any of PHPExcel classes and methods
$this->load->file(APPPATH.'libraries/PHPExcel.php'); //full path to 

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();//change by filetype
try {
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); //you file name
} catch (Exception $e) {
    show_error($e->getMessage());
}
```

tested on CI 2.1.3 &&  PHPExcel 1.7.8

Answer (score -1):

I follow these instructions for the integration between CodeIgniter and PHPExcel.

Create a new PHP file inside CI’s `application/libraries/` and name it Excel.php.

```
require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel.php";
class Excel extends PHPExcel {
 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct(); 
 } 
}
```

To follow the full instructions visit [Easily Integrateload Phpexcel Into Codeigniter Framework](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework/).